# Is it possible to store an vector inside a dataframe cell?

Tags: r

I´m trying to create an dataframe which is holding an ID and an numeric vector with an unknown count of grades per row, but I don´t know how to do this.

```
studentmean <-
    data.frame(
      Student = character(),
      Grades = c(0),
      stringsAsFactors = FALSE
    )
```

Later I am trying to add a new row to the dataframe using:

```
gradeList <- getGradesOfStudent(data$ResultFrame, matriculationNumber)$Grades
    studentmean[nrow(studentmean) + 1, ] = list(as.character(matriculationNumber), gradeList
```

How is it possible to store an vector of numeric values inside a single dataframe cell?

Comment: You need to add it as list. If you share a reproducible example of your data along with expected output we can help you more

Comment: You certainly can store a list inside the cell of a data.frame. However unless you are an expert R programmer and have a very good reason to do so (e.g storing a linear model in the same row as the predictors) then I strongly suggest you don't. Instead have multiple rows for each value of the numeric vector with the same ID. This will be much less a headache.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with Stephen Henderson's comment that you shouldn't use list-columns unless you are absolutely sure that they are the best way to solve your specific problem. That being said, if you do decide to use list columns, you might want to consider using tibbles instead of data frames. Tibbles are an 'upgrade' to regular data frames. They are part of the tidyverse and come in the `tibble` package.

Tibbles make it easy to create list columns:

```
tibble(x = 1:3, y = list(1:5, 1:10, 1:20))

#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>       x y         
#>   <int> <list>    
#> 1     1 <int [5]> 
#> 2     2 <int [10]>
#> 3     3 <int [20]>
```

Moreover, you can "pack" and "unpack" list-columns using the commands `nest` and `unnest` from the `tidyr` package. For example:

```
df <- tibble(
  x = 1:3,
  y = c("a", "d,e,f", "g,h")
)
df %>%
  transform(y = strsplit(y, ",")) %>%
  unnest(y)
```

For more information about tibbles you can consult this [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tibble/vignettes/tibble.html).

Answer (score 4):

Yes of course :) A `data.frame` is a `list` and therefore you can nest difference data structures inside it:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c("a", "b", "c"))
df$c <- list(c(1, 2, 3), c(4,5,6), c(7,8,9))

> str(df)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ a: num  1 2 3
 $ b: Factor w/ 3 levels "a","b","c": 1 2 3
 $ c:List of 3
  ..$ : num  1 2 3
  ..$ : num  4 5 6
  ..$ : num  7 8 9
```